# ImageJ how to copy a Polygon

Tags: java, imagej

i've got a polygon on the default image, and the selected polygon.
How can i copy the polygon or the selection, or how can i draw the same polygon on a new image?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After drawing a selection in one image, you can copy that selection to a second image by activating the second image window, then running the `Restore Selection` command. It lives in the `Selection` submenu of the `Edit` menu. You can also execute it using the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+E (or Cmd+Shift+E on OS X).

If you want to actually bake the polygon into the image itself, you can use the `Flatten` command in the `Overlay` submenu of the `Image` menu. And the shortcut for that Ctrl+Shift+F (or Cmd+Shift+F on OS X).